# are javascript const really constant? in redux?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

I have this reducer in my store, where the initial state `initialProcessingState` is imported from another source file.

```
import {
  ACTN_IS_PROCESSING
} from '../config/action-types.js';

import { initialProcessingState } from "./redProcessing-initial.js";

export default function (state = initialProcessingState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case ACTN_IS_PROCESSING:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.isProcessing
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

here is how is defined in the source file:

```
export const initialProcessingState = {
  keys: [],
  mostRecentStatus: false,
  neverStale: true
}
```

Now my store is persisting state into localstorage with subscribe

```
  store.subscribe(() => {
    updateLocalStorage(store);
  })
```

Like this...

```
import { initialProcessingState } from "../reducers/redProcessing-initial.js";

var updateLocalStorage = debounce((store) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  var _state = {
    ...state,
    isProcessing: { ...initialProcessingState }
  };
  localStorage.setItem('reduxState', JSON.stringify(_state))
}, 100);
```

Where my intent is to overwrite `isProcessing` with it's **initial state**, defined as `const` above in `initialProcessingState`.

**Unfortunately doesn't work.** Because every single time `updateLocalStorage` is called the value of `initialProcessingState` is not the initial value, but the current updated state by subsequent reducer calls.

How is it possible? It's a `const`.

**My temporary fix is** involve `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialProcessingState))`:

```
const _initialProcessingState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialProcessingState));

var updateLocalStorage = debounce((store) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  //this is not the best way
  console.log("updateLocalStorage", "initialProcessingState", initialProcessingState, _initialProcessingState);
  var _state = {
    ...state,
    isProcessing: { ..._initialProcessingState }
  };
  localStorage.setItem('reduxState', JSON.stringify(_state))
}, 100);
```

And the following was not enough to make it working:

```
const _initialProcessingState = initialProcessingState;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: javascript constants are not the same as in other languages. constants are not immutable. if you constant refers to an object or array the object can be changed, you just can't reassign the const.

Comment: To clarify this: what is constant about a `const` is the reference to the object/value. This can not be changed. The Object itself and its properties can be mutated. Think `const biologicalFather = {...};` this is constant, this won't ever change. `biologicalFather.facialHair` is not constant. And all the changes will apply to / be visible to everyone who has a reference to him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the
>   content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its
>   properties) can be altered.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

## EDIT

It might be important to mention `Object.freeze()` as @Apolo pointed out in his comment.

#### Objects

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object. A frozen object can no
>   longer be changed; freezing an object prevents new properties from
>   being added to it, existing properties from being removed, prevents
>   changing the enumerability, configurability, or writability of
>   existing properties, and prevents the values of existing properties
>   from being changed. In addition, freezing an object also prevents its
>   prototype from being changed.

With `Object.freeze()` however it's also important to note that it's not extended to the values that the frozen **object** holds:

> Note that values [of Objects] that are objects can still be modified, unless they
>   are also frozen.

#### Arrays

> As an object, an array can be frozen; after doing so, its elements
>   cannot be altered and no elements can be added to or removed from the
>   array.

Source in the **EDIT** section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: Would be nice to add a word about `Object.freeze` for those looking for ways to create immutable objects (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/freeze)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `initialProcessingState` is a reference to an object. That value cannot change.

The object it references *can* be *mutated*.

Answer (score 1):

`const` means that the reference can't be reassigned. That's why in the case of assigning strings or numbers they remain immutable but when assigning objects and arrays, its content can be modified through their reference making them not immutable.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the
>   content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its
>   properties) can be altered.

```
const foo = { bar : 'baz' };
foo.bar = 'foo'; // works, because it doesn't change what foo is.
foo = null; // will fail, since it tries to change what foo is
```

You could look into [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), but that only freezes the first level:

```js
const foo = Object.freeze({
  bar : 'baz',
  baz : { foo : 'bar'}
});

foo.bar = 'foo'; // will not change since foo is frozen
foo.baz.foo = 'foo';  // will change, since foo.baz is not frozen 
console.dir(foo)
```